# Understanding different fields of output of sensors

Tags: hardware, temperature

Here's the output of `sensors` command:

```
thinkpad-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
fan1:        3414 RPM

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +50.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +47.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +49.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +49.0°C  (crit = +99.0°C)
```

What is the `Physical id 0` device, and how does the virtual device works here? Where does the data come from?

Comment: Did you start `# sensors-detect` before that?

Comment: And this may be related: http://www.lm-sensors.org/wiki/FAQ/Chapter3#Somesensorsaredoublydetected